# Mixing colors with bitfields in C with bitwise operators?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-fields

I was reading the Wikipedia entry on [bit-fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field), and saw how one might use binary numbers to represent primary colors and combine them using bitwise OR (`|`) operators. I want to check if one color is contained in another.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// primary colors
#define RED 0b001
#define GREEN 0b010
#define BLUE 0b100

// mixed colors 
#define BLACK 0b000
#define YELLOW (RED | GREEN)
#define MAGENTA (RED | BLUE)
#define CYAN (BLUE | GREEN)
#define WHITE (RED | GREEN | BLUE)

int main(void) 
{
    int magenta = MAGENTA;
    int blue = BLUE;

#define in &  // check if a color A is contained in another color B:
    printf("%s\n", blue in magenta ? "true" : "false"); // true
    printf("%s\n", magenta in blue ? "true" : "false"); // should be false but is true.
    return 0;
}
```

I understand why this happens but is there is a bitwise operation or combination thereof that achieves the result I want ?

Comment: `(magenta & blue) == magenta`

Comment: You are changing `&` to `in` to make it look more like natural language. The `&` operator meanwhile doesn't care in which order the left and right arguments are in. It simply checks if the bits are set.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: No, it is not.

Comment: But `&` is symmetric. so A & B == B & A. Having refined `&` to look like asymmetric relation 'in' you've confused yourself.

Comment: `#define in &` - Writing code like that is _extremely bad_ practice. Bad like instantly fired from the C programming job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to check if all primary colors of a given color `a` are also part of another color `b` you could do it with a function like this (and as @Andrew Henle correctly mentioned, better use unsigned types for bit fields):

```
unsigned contains( unsigned b, unsigned a )  // returns != 0 if all primary colors of a are also part of b
{
  return ( b & a ) == a;
}
```

and use it like that

```
unsigned magenta = MAGENTA;
unsigned blue = BLUE;

printf("%s\n", contains( magenta, blue ) ? "true" : "false"); // true
printf("%s\n", contains( blue, magenta ) ? "true" : "false"); // false
```

Comment: Using `unsigned int` for bitwise-operations is much better than `int`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle you're right of course. Fixed

Comment: Using bitwise operators as some sort of color logic is simply a very bad idea to begin with. `contains(WHITE, BLACK)` Oh nice, white contains black. The OP should just forget about the whole thing and move on.